# Characterization of the center of a polygon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons, centroid

Let $O$ be the circumcenter of the regular polygon $P_n$. Then for any $A\in P_n$ one has $d(A,O)\leq r$, where $d$ is the usual Euclidean distance and $r$ is the polygon's circumradius.

Prove that this property uniquely determines the point $O$.

Comment: That appears to be the definition of the circumcenter (center of circumcircle), not the centroid (average position of points in the polygon)

Comment: I might have confused the English terms, sorry . .. it is supposed to be a regular n-gon and the centroid I am talking about is the center of the figure, so also the circumcentre. I fixed the original post

Comment: Prove it for $n=3$, then consider any three vertices of $P_n$.

Comment: Have you thought about my suggestion, Phantom?

Comment: I apologize for my late answer and I appreciate your concern and your suggestion. I did think about it a little, but I am unable to complete the proof. I tried, as you suggested, to consider a triangle, say ABC, and a point P different from O. It seems Obvious that d(P,X) is > r for (at least) one of A,B,C, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Given any triangle, there's a unique point, the circumcenter, equidistant from all three vertices (since the circumcenter must be on the perpendicular bisector of each of the three sides).

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: Somehow, in the sense that I think the fact you hinted uses the fact that equality is actually attained (at the polygon's vertices). Could this additional fact not be used, but just the inequality?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. If $P$ is different from the circumcenter of a triangle, then it can't be on all three perpendicular bisectors. If it's not on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, then one of $d(P,A),d(P,B)$ is strictly bigger than the other one.

Comment: I mean that this proof seems to use the fact that d(O,A)=d(O,B)=d(O,C)=r, but the given property does not include the hypothesis that we indeed have equality for those vertices. We are only given that the distances are <= r.

Comment: Please replace O with P in my previois reply. Am I wrong? Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a point in the plane. We say that $X$ is a *central point* of $P_n$ if $d(A,X)\leq r$ for all $A \in P_n$.

If $\sigma$ is a symmetry of $P_n$ and $X$ is a central point, then so is $\sigma(X)$.

Thus, set of central points is fixed by all symmetries of $P_n$. But the only point fixed by all symmetries of $P_n$ is its circumcenter $O$.

Comment: " But the only point fixed by all symmetries of Pn is its circumcenter O." Why is that?

Comment: @PhantomR, it's the only point fixed by the rotations of angle $2\pi/n$.

Comment: Ok, but then, what about the fact that $\sigma(x)$ is also a central point if $x$ is?

Comment: @PhantomR, rotations and reflections preserve distances.

Comment: Oh, I'm really stupid right now.. So d(s(X),A) = d(s(X), s(A')) (since s is a symmetry such that s(Pn)=Pn, there exists A' in Pn such that A=s(A')) = d(X,A') (s is a symmetry) <= r. This makes sense. Thank you!.